# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. While I am trying to make an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make an insert into my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "FittingOldSystem" (
    "fittingOldSystemId" INT NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "address_1" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "add_2" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "add_3" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "add_4" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "add_5" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "county" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "date" DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "order_no" VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "phone" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "rep" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "house_no" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fit_date" DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fitters" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "site_add1" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "site_add2" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "site_add3" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "site_add4" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "site_add5" VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fullAddress" VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "cus_comm_1" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "telno_h" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "telno_w" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fitcomm" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "custcomm" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "direct" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "contact" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fittno" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "finish" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "totwind" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "totdoor" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "totpatio" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "totboards" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "totframes" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okwind" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okdoors" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okframes" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okpatio" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "notfitted" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "delvonly" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okunits" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okseal" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okdeliver" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okboards" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okdirect" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okmeasure" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "okadvert" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "chgrep" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "sercode" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "prod_week" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "sername" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "jobcomp" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "datecomp" DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "north" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "signature" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "loadCode" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "remake" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "serfollow" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "externalft" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "oketc" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "glassbrk" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "glassbl" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "bkpanehigh" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "datasrc" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "schdno" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "formcomp" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "remakemeas" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "archive" VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "scode" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "pcode" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "acode" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "acntcode" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "countryCode" CHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "instanceProcessedId" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "fosId" INT NOT NULL,
    "fittStatus" VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX "UNIQUE" ("fosId")
)
;
```

with the following line(this is only 1 insert of over 1000 rows I must insert):

```
INSERT INTO mj.FittingOldSystem(fittingOldSystemId, name, address_1, add_2, add_3, add_4, add_5, county, date, order_no, phone, rep, house_no, fit_date, fitters, type, site_add1, site_add2, site_add3, site_add4, site_add5, fullAddress, cus_comm_1, telno_h, telno_w, fitcomm, custcomm, direct, contact, fittno, finish, totwind, totdoor, totpatio, totboards, totframes, okwind, okdoors, okframes, okpatio, notfitted, delvonly, okunits, okseal, okdeliver, okboards, okdirect, okmeasure, okadvert, chgrep, sercode, prod_week, sername, jobcomp, datecomp, north, signature, loadCode, remake, serfollow, externalft, oketc, glassbrk, glassbl, bkpanehigh, datasrc, schdno, formcomp, remakemeas, archive, scode, pcode, acode, acntcode, countryCode, instanceProcessedId, fosId, fittStatus) VALUES
    (2036446,'Newline Homes','Unit 3','Coolmine Centre','Coolmine Ind Est','Dublin 15','NULL','NULL',convert(datetime,'2019-05-07 09:08:56.130000', 121),'6900156','NULL','BF','1718','2019-05-21','D04','N','156','Allendale Strip','Hausfield','Dublin 15','NULL','Unit 3, Coolmine Centre, Coolmine Ind Est, Dublin 15156, Allendale Strip, Hausfield, Dublin 15','NULL','0838979692','NULL','NULL','NULL','N53 23.4000000 W6 25.8270000 ','NULL',2036446,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',19,'NULL','NULL','NULL','False','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','IE','NULL',94394873,'NULL')
```

But I keep getting the following code:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have tried to use [], '', "" for the column date and fit_date. It did not work.

Also I tried to use `convert(datetime,'2019-05-07 09:08:56.130000', 121)`. Not working yet

Comment: `convert(datetime,'2019-05-07 09:08:56.130000', 121)` look up [format 121](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and see if it matches the string you are using.

Comment: try this with your date time.. 'select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(23),'2019-05-07 09:08:56.130000'),121)'

Comment: I have tried to use convert, forgot to mention it, sorry. Its not the answer.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have just tried that, still the same error.

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes it does, please, can you show me how did you use it? Maybe I missing something

Comment: you can't put 130000 for millisecond it is max 999

Comment: @DaleBurrell I am afraid is not working like that.

Comment: Yes, when I exported the data from SQL Server 2014, the tool made it like that, I have fixed that but still is not working.

Comment: please run select getdate() and put the result here

Comment: this is what comes up: 2019-05-21 20:02:06.477

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, the solution at the end was not a convert, was a cast like this:

cast('2019-05-07 09:08:56.130' as datetime) "with the suggestion of the .130 over 130000"

and replacing all 'NULL' with just NULL, without quotation marks

this last one was the principal problem.